# Windows 10 with wampserver - php cli without colors

Tags: php, windows, symfony, command-line, colors

There's a problem with my CLI in windows 10

Some time ago i've upgraded my windows version and it completely messed up my config

I'm using wampserver

[image]

**EDIT:** there are no colors in CLI only those weird tags I am wondering if it's problem with my system or wamp

It's been like 3 weeks and I still haven't got any proper answer

Please help!

[Another ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs9SR.png) just shows how bad it looks

Comment: So what is it you want to change, that might help us help you

Comment: We can't really help you without anymore details? What isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a PHP or Symphony specific question.

Comment: And _Messed up you config?_ Your config of WHAT?

Comment: Add some error or details...

Comment: @RiggsFolly look at ss - there are no colors in cli it's just weird and by config i mean both windows and wamp config

Comment: Is this any good to you http://superuser.com/questions/609470/how-to-reset-the-looks-of-the-command-prompt-window-in-windows

Comment: Now what do you think is wrong with your WAMPServer config

Comment: Still nothing i followed those instructions

I'm also having problem with guzzlehttp error while instaling Symfony with regular symfony installer